# how to Authenticate 2 web api tokens in android

Tags: java, android

I am looking for the best method of having my users have a login for my app, and based on that login, be able to authorise them to at the moment, another 2 web APIs. This will grow to many in the future but for now i'm trying to find the best practise for this.

As an example, IFTTT and smartthings, have a login for their users but also are able to manage their uses recipies for their 3rd party api services.

Again what would be the best method for this. I would preferably not want a user to login into the other services once logged into the app, it should already do this for them.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to automatically link the other services. The user should have the ultimate decision whether to provide the necessary information to link your app to their other accounts

Comment: Sorry let me re-phrase a little, I agree that the user will have to initially do subsequent logins to request their tokens. but for the purpose of the above I will supply a user and pass for both services i call. I am just trying to prove concept before expanding.

Comment: Still not sure I follow. Where is the limitation? Implementing the third-party login or calling your 2 web API upon login success?

Comment: So after the initial login i want to call the 2 web apis and store their respective tokens to use within an app, since the functions of their respective calls will both need auth tokens. one will be to control heating and one will be controlling a host of other smart home stuff i have linked up. I could easily make 2 seperate apps but i am wanting to use both 3rd party restfull services in the same app.